# Is there a way to extract all elements of a list in place

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

Im looking for a way to extract all the elements of a list in common lisp. Like this

```
[194]> (break-out-of-list '(a b c d))
A
B
C
D
```

Edit: The usage example I gave was not thought out very well, however I'm still curious if it is possible to break out of a list like in the example above.

Comment: what does 'extract' or 'break out' mean? what does it do? if you want to print list elements to the terminal, map print over them.

Comment: With extract I mean the inverse of list. A function where `(break-list '((a b c)) )` would return `(a b c)

Comment: The 'inverse'? What is that? In your example you just take the first element. Maybe you mean some kind of 'flatten', where all atoms in a list or its sublists are moved into a single flat list?

Comment: Ok, what I want is some construct such that: `(some-macro (break-list '(a b c d)))` is equivalent to `(some-macro 'a 'b 'c 'd)`. For functions I could use apply as Chris Jester-Young pointed out below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you demonstrate seems to be the question how to get the elements of a list as *multiple values*:

```
CL-USER> (values 1 2 3)
1
2
3
CL-USER> (apply #'values '(1 2 3))
1
2
3
```

See also `multiple-value-bind` and `nth-value` in the hyperspec.

Answer (score 4):

While `(apply #'values '(1 2 3))` works there is also a function to this called `values-list` which is used like this:

```
(values-list '(1 2 3))
```

And it has the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use `apply`:

```
(defun wraptest (&rest arguments)
  (apply #'test arguments))
```

This technically doesn't "break out of list"; it simply uses a list's elements as arguments to a function call.

(Disclaimer: I'm a Schemer, not a Common Lisper, and there may be a more-idiomatic way to achieve the same result in CL.)

Comment: You're right, that works for the example I gave. However the example I gave was a bit flawed so I removed it. I'm mostly curious if a break out of list function or operator exists

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for this:

http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/macros.html#LtohTOCentry-2

> That's mostly all there is to backquote. There are just two extra
>   items to point out. First, if you write ",@e" instead of ",e" then the
>   value of e is spliced into the result. So if v=(oh boy), then `(zap
>   ,@v ,v) evaluates to (zap oh boy (oh boy)). The second occurrence of v
>   is replaced by its value. The first is replaced by the elements of its
>   value. If v had had value (), it would have disappeared entirely: the
>   value of (zap ,@v ,v) would have been (zap ()), which is the same as
>   (zap nil).

Reading your comments:

> (some-macro (break-list '(a b c d))) is equivalent to (some-macro 'a 'b 'c 'd)

With this, you could do:

```
`(some-macro ,@'(a b c d))
```

and you'd get:

```
(some-macro a b c d)
```

Comment: But since I have to use backquote in order to use ,@ I'm still left with the outer list. But yes I'm looking for a equivalent of the,@ operator that can be used without backquote.

Comment: I think you can use it anyway, example underway ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't I have to write a macro that returns `(some-macro ,@'(a b c d)) to use this?