# Common lisp values-list function

Tags: common-lisp

I have this function:

```
(defun call-generic-function (gf &rest args)
    (let* ((applicable-methods (compute-applicable-methods gf  args))
            (most-specific-method (select-next-method-to-call  
                applicable-methods)))
        (print "applicable methods")
        (print (length applicable-methods))  
        (print args)
        (print (values-list args))
        (funcall (method-function most-specific-method)
              (values-list args)         
              (remove most-specific-method applicable-methods))))
```

I expect `values-list` to give me all the elements of the list `args` (these are two objects to be passed as two out of the three expected arguments to the called method by funcall) but it only gives the first element and I get an error that I am only supplying 2 arguments instead of the expected 3 arguments. This can be confirmed by the fact that  `(print args)` prints a list of 2 objects but `(print (values-list args))` prints out just the first of these objects. How can I correct this?

**results (print args):**

```
(#S(OBJECT
    :CLASS #S(CLASS
              :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS #S(CLASS
                                    :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS #S(CLASS
                                                          :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS NIL
                                                          :DIRECT-SLOTS NIL)
                                    :DIRECT-SLOTS (NAME ADDRESS))
              :DIRECT-SLOTS (EMPLOYER))
    :SLOTS #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 3 {1003932403}>)
 #S(OBJECT
    :CLASS #S(CLASS
              :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS #S(CLASS
                                    :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS NIL
                                    :DIRECT-SLOTS NIL)
              :DIRECT-SLOTS (SPORTS))
    :SLOTS #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 1 {1003932853}>))
```

**result (print (values-list args))**

```
#S(OBJECT
   :CLASS #S(CLASS
             :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS #S(CLASS
                                   :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS #S(CLASS
                                                         :DIRECT-SUPERCLASS NIL
                                                         :DIRECT-SLOTS NIL)
                                   :DIRECT-SLOTS (NAME ADDRESS))
             :DIRECT-SLOTS (EMPLOYER))
   :SLOTS #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 3 {1003932403}>)
```

As you can see, values-list gets just the first object and makes my function which expects both objects fail.

Comment: What did you expect `values-list` to do?

Comment: For example,(+ (values-list '(1 2))) should give me 3. That is what I thought, but i gives me 1

Comment: ... why would it do that? I don't think `+` does anything special with multiple-values.

Comment: Shock on me. I saw it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243813/is-there-a-way-to-extract-all-elements-of-a-list-in-place. Was thinking I can achieve " (+ (values-list '(1 2))) = 3" with it. What can I use to dynamically retrieve all the elements of a list and pass them to a function as individual elements?

Comment: I think you want [`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm#apply), not `funcall`.

Comment: This (apply #'+ '(1 2)) will work for addition but my for my function it does not work. I do not see how I would use it as my function takes two objects and a list of methods. I was wondering if there is a function that can break a list '(1 2) into 1 2 that I can use for my function.

Comment: Like this? https://tio.run/##ZY1RCsMgEET/PcVgP7pCCiYn6FGqRiEgxqYG2l7eaiMlofsxu8u8nTV@esScabRuDXDzDFLQMIIBFOMyhQS1X/R@MUIwRt4mELmA07kEVL8WleR06beOXkoMUoqjOzSXlzsOrtXy1XfR@7o@uWg8qRj9C@VFnWwYcQjfsv7hG3XXBnY/JucP

Comment: I try this  (apply (method-function most-specific-method)
              (append args (remove most-specific-method applicable-methods))). It says "invalid number of arguments". The second list, when appended to the first list, generates more arguments which are not desired. Is there a way to append it as just a list which can be expanded later inside the function? As it is, its individual elements are appended raising an argument length error.

Comment: Oh just figured it out. You are the best. You should post that answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let’s see what happens with `values-list`:

```
CL-USER> (values-list '(1 2 3))
1 ;
2
3
```

This function takes a list and returns its items as multiple values. The way that multiple values works is that in most situations the multiple values are removed and only the first is used (if no values are returned then `NIL` is used):

```
CL-USER> (list (values-list '(1 2 3)))
(1)
```

There are ways to use multiple values or to call a function with multiple arguments:

```
CL-USER> (apply #'list 4 '(1 2 3))
(4 1 2 3)
CL-USER> (multiple-value-call #'list (values 4 5) (values-list '(1 2 3)))
(4 5 1 2 3)
```

Note however that in your question you seem to want to call print with multiple arguments:

```
CL-USER> (print 1 2)
;; error because 2 is not an output stream
```

If you want to print each item of the list then you can use a loop or format:

```
CL-USER> (loop for item in '(1 2 3) do (print item))
1
2
3
NIL
CL-USER> (format t "~{~a~%~}" '(1 2 3))
1
2
3
NIL
```

If you want to call a function with an arbitrary number of arguments in the middle then:

```
CL-USER> (apply #'list 1 (append '(1 2) (list 3)))
(1 1 2 3)
CL-USER> (multiple-value-call #'list 1 (values-list '(1 2)) 3)
(1 1 2 3)
```

But in your case I think the actual solution is to pass the list of applicable methods in the first argument rather than the last.